# Add rules to Spacy lemmatization

Tags: nlp, spacy

I am using Spacy lemmatization for preprocessing texts.

```
doc = 'ups'
for i in nlp(doc):
print(i.lemma_)
>> up
```

I understand why spacy remove the 's', but it is important for me that in that case, it won't do it. Is there a way to add specific rules to spacy or do I have to use If statements outside the process (which is something I don't want to do )

Comment: There are internal tables of lookups and rules that you can customize, but the details depend on how `nlp` is configured. Which model/language is loaded and does the pipeline contain a tagger?

Comment: The pipeline is used for lemmatization only. i use : nlp.pipe(sentence.split(),disable=["parser","ner"]) . to run on every word as a "lonely" word in the context. any idea how to change the process to include the lemmatizer rules just for those cases without losing all the other?

Comment: What is `nlp`, though?

Comment: en_core_web_sm model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For spacy v2:

Depending on whether you have a tagger, you can customize the rule-based lemmatizer exceptions or the lookup table:

```py
import spacy

# original
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm", disable=["parser", "ner"])
# may be "up" or "ups" depending on exact version of spacy/model because it
# depends on the POS tag
assert nlp("ups")[0].lemma_ in ("ups", "up")

# 1. Exception for rule-based lemmatizer (with tagger)

# reload to start with a clean lemma cache
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm", disable=["parser", "ner"])
# add an exception for "ups" as with POS NOUN or VERB
nlp.vocab.lookups.get_table("lemma_exc")["noun"]["ups"] = ["ups"]
nlp.vocab.lookups.get_table("lemma_exc")["verb"]["ups"] = ["ups"]
assert nlp("ups")[0].lemma_ == "ups"

# 2. New entry for lookup lemmatizer (without tagger)

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm", disable=["tagger", "parser", "ner"])
nlp.vocab.lookups.get_table("lemma_lookup")["ups"] = "ups"
assert nlp("ups")[0].lemma_ == "ups"
```

If you are processing words in isolation, the tagger is not going to be very reliable (you might get `NOUN`, `PROPN`, or `VERB` for something like `ups`), so it might be easier to deal with customizing the lookup lemmatizer. The quality of the rule-based lemmas is better overall, but you need at least full phrases, preferably full sentences, to get reasonable results.

Comment: what is the difference from just adding 'if value == 'ups' : lemma = 'ups' " ? is there a way to change directly the tables/model and then save it with the changes? i don't want my code base to be full of rules for specific words each time I'm using the nlp = spacy.load( ..)

Comment: If you save the modified model with `nlp.to_disk()`, then you can reload that customized model without making the changes again. You can use `spacy package` to package the saved directory into a package you can install with `pip` like `en_core_web_sm` if you like, but you can also just load from the saved directory path.

Answer (score 4):

In Spacy 3 the accepted solution throws an error:

```py
KeyError: "[E159] Can't find table 'lemma_exc' in lookups. Available tables: ['lexeme_norm']"
```

As the `lemmatizer` is now a dedicated Spacy component the lookups have to be modified directly at the component *(this at least works for me)*:

```py
nlp.get_pipe('lemmatizer').lookups.get_table("lemma_exc")["noun"]["data"] = ["data"]
```

Hope this is helpful to someone!